# reinitializing javascript object's properties

Tags: javascript, object, reset

In my Javascript drag and drop build app, a variety of buildings can be built. The specific characteristics of these are all saved in one object, like

```
var buildings = {
house: ['#07DA21',12,12,0,20],
bank: ['#E7DFF2',16,16,0,3],
stadium: ['#000000',12,12,0,1],
townhall: ['#2082A8',20,8,0,1],
etcetera
}
```

So every building has a number of characteristics, like color, size, look which can be called as buildings[townhall][0] (referring to the color). The object changes as the user changes things. When clicking 'reset' however, the whole object should be reset to its initial settings again to start over, but I have no idea how to do that. For normal objects it is something like.

```
function building() {}
var building = new building();
delete building;
var building2 = new building();
```

You can easily delete and remake it, so the properties are reset. But my object is automatically initialized. Is there a way to turn my object into something that can be deleted and newly created, without making it very complicating, or a better way to store this information?

Comment: You can't `delete` properties declared in global scope, nor can you `delete` functions. See http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/#property_attributes

Comment: That's an interesting read, but is there some way to set up my code differently then, so that it is not global, thus deletable, like the example of the objects declared with 'new'?

Comment: @Marcel, of course you can delete global variables (variables as you don't declare properties).

Comment: @Sean: Have you actually tried it? E.g.: `var foo=1; console.log(delete foo);` outputs `false`.

Comment: @Marcel, I was fooled by the fact that console uses `eval` which, behaves differently (as noted in the article).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a copy/clone method to restore the original state

```
var defaults = {
    foo: "bar"
};
var building;

function reset(){
    building = {};
    for (var key in defaults) {
        if (defaults.hasOwnProperty(key){
            building[key] = defaults[key];
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can just call `reset()` whenever you need to have `building` reset.

Answer (score 3):

You can keep initial state as a prototype on an object.

```
var Base = function(){};
    Base.prototype={a:1,b:2};
var c = new Base();
```

Now, you can change value of a or b to whatever you want.
To restore, just use

```
delete c.a or delete c.b
```

You will get your initial value back.
Hope this help.